# Integrating the Onsager formulated mass transport equation for a binary mixture

Tags: chemical-engineering

I want to develop a model for the Maxwell-Stefan mass Diffusion for a binary mixture for a nano porous membrane. I have permeation data and adsorption isotherms measured I just need to implement the formulation...
So based on the Onsager formulation I have:

$$\begin{align}
N_{1,z}&=-RT \cdot \left[\frac{L_{11}(p_{1},p_{2})}{p_{1}}\frac{dp_{1}}{dz}+  \frac{L_{12}(p_{1},p_{2})}{p_{2} }\frac{dp_{2}}{dz}\right]  \\
N_{2,z}&=-RT \cdot \left[\frac{L_{21}(p_{1},p_{2})}{p_{1}}\frac{dp_{1}}{dz}+  \frac{L_{22}(p_{1},p_{2})}{p_{2} }\frac{dp_{2}}{dz}\right]
\end{align}$$
with:
$$
\begin{align}
L_{11} &= \frac{1}{RT}\frac{Đ_{1} q_{sat} \rho_{p} \theta_{1} \left(Đ_{12} + Đ_{2} \theta_{1}\right)}{ \left(Đ_{12} + Đ_{1} \theta_{2} + Đ_{2} \theta_{1}\right)} \\
L_{22} &= \frac{1}{RT}\frac{Đ_{2} q_{sat} \rho_{p} \theta_{2} \left(Đ_{12} + Đ_{1} \theta_{2}\right)}{\left(Đ_{12} + Đ_{1} \theta_{2} + Đ_{2} \theta_{1}\right)} \\
L_{12} &= \frac{1}{RT}\frac{Đ_{1} Đ_{2} q_{sat} \rho_{p} \theta_{1} \theta_{2}}{\left(Đ_{12} + Đ_{1} \theta_{2} + Đ_{2} \theta_{1}\right)}\\
L_{21} &= L_{12}\\
\text{with:}\\
\theta_{i} &= \frac{ \exp\Big[\Big(\frac{RT\ln(p_{i}/p^{LV})}{\varepsilon}\Big)^{2}\Big]}{p_{i}} 
\end{align}
$$
So my L_{11}, L_{12}, L_{21} and L_{22} parameters are functions of p1 and p2.

Given values are:
p1 and p2 at z=0 and z=δ.
The temperature T is constant over the membrane.
Đ_12 can be calculated by the Vignes formulation.
So I need to integrate the equations for $N_1$ and $N_2$

I have a hard time understanding how I can implement the solution to this numerically in python. I tried a lot and with all tries I ended up realizing I didn't understand the problem properly.

So do you guys have any idea how a code based on scipy.integrate could look like?

Thanks a bunch and have a great day!

Comment: Is this really a problem with mathematics?

Comment: Are $p_i$ going to vary with total pressure? And have you got as far as integrating for each $\theta_i$? I'm interested in where the expression for $\theta_i$ comes from, it isn't very familiar-looking.

Comment: [edit] I corrected a mistake in the adsorption isotherm. It is the DA isotherm but with bad luck I cpoied the one with the integral from my notes. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @SolarMike no I don't think it's a problem with mathematics. I just don't see the solution yet.

Comment: @GeoffreyLiddell Thanks for your comment. $p_{i}$ will not vary with total pressure. The description for L_{kl} is a function of  $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ and these are functions of $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ respectively. So I am having a hard time integratin that one for the two pressures...

Comment: I think the main question is: Can I evalute the both terms in each equation on its own and then just add the terms or how could I arrive at a solution for $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$?

Comment: Do the commas on the N's mean partial derivative with respect to z?

Comment: If you don't want to use FEM or something like that I am not sure how to do it. It looks to me like it is of the form F(x)*dx/dz=0 or something like that, I don't know how to get a system of first order ODEs from that.